# How to handle a random spawner of obstacles in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, game-development

I'm trying to handle a object spawner but it isn't work as i wish. It should create a new object every time my timer pass the maxTime of the object, but it does it just once and in the wrong position (out of my range).
Here is my code:

```c
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxTime = 10;
    private float timer = 0;
    public GameObject obstacle;
    private float width = (Screen.width)/2; //It doesn't recognize width as the variable that refeers the width of the screen, so i tried it
    private float maxTime0 = 10;
    public int pontos = 5;
    public float score;

    void Start() {
        GameObject new_obstacle = Instantiate(obstacle);
        new_obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-width, width), 0, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(timer > maxTime) {
            GameObject new_obstacle = Instantiate(obstacle);
            new_obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-width, width), 0, 0);
            if(new_obstacle.transform.position.y < (Screen.height - 7)){
                DestroyImmediate(new_obstacle, true);
            }
            timer = 0; 
            maxTime = 0.9f * maxTime;
        }
        score += pontos; 
        timer += Time.deltaTime; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So what would be the correct position? Did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code line by line to see where exactly it stops "working"?

Comment: The "correct position" should be with y between -width and width (-width<=y<= width), but it creates an obstacle out of my screen. And the rest of the code continues to work, the score and maxTime are being modified, the only problem is that it doesn't create the objects.

Comment: no, as you have it it will not be `y` but rather `x` ... `y` is always `0` in your vector .. the position depends on the position of that object of course since you add it to `transform.position`  ...

Comment: is it also desired that your score grows by `5` **each frame**? what if on one device your code runs with 30fps and on a better one with 120fps?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, it should b the x who is between -width and width. y have to be 0, cause i have an object_spawner, out of my screen, where i set this script, so i can generate the objects out of my screen( in the top of it) and it will pass the screen while falling. The problem is that the object is created at the side of my screen.

Comment: if it happens only exactly once it sounds like it happens only in `Start` but never in `Update`?

Comment: About the score, I made it cause I want to increase it based on the time played. I hadn't thought about the fps difference, do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: for the score yes: multiply it by `Time.deltaTime` to convert from value per frame into value per second ;)

Comment: Yes! It seems that the Update doesn't work...
And thank you, I will try to fix the score!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the main issue is that you spawn the object in **pixel** coordinates since `Screen.width` is the Screens width in **pixels**.

But what you rather want is spawning in the extends of the `Camera`'s frustrum.

Unity provides a way of finding that [Frustrum Size At Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html).

Since you then also check

```
   if(new_obstacle.transform.position.y < (Screen.height - 7))
```

to destroy your object I bet your `Update` indeed spawns the object but immediately destroys them!

Reason: Your spawner is in World coordinates and probably **always** under the `Screen.height - 7` which is in pixel coordinates!

Since you don't have this check in `Start` it is the only time that it "works" for you.

If you really need this check at all you would need to convert the position into screen pixel space using [`Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)

```
Camera camera;

void Start() 
{
    camera = Camera.main;
    // assuming that your camera points exactly forward (2D game like)
    var distance = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z - camera.tramsform.position.z);
    var frustumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    var frustrumWidth = frustumHeight * camera.aspect;

    // not anymore in pixel space but frustrum width in world coordinates
    // at the z distance of the spawner
    width = frustrumWidth / 2f;


    var new_obstacle = Instantiate(obstacle);
    new_obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.right * Random.Range(-width, width);
}

void Update()
{
    if(timer > maxTime) 
    {
        var new_obstacle = Instantiate(obstacle);
        new_obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.right * Random.Range(-width, width);

        if(camera.WorldToScreenPoint(new_obstacle.transform.position).y < Screen.height - 7)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(new_obstacle, true);
        }
        
        timer = 0; 
        maxTime = 0.9f * maxTime;
    }

    // as mentioned here multiply by Time.deltaTime in order to
    // convert from pontos per frame into pontos per second
    score += pontos * Time.deltaTime; 
    timer += Time.deltaTime; 
}
```

and yes then you could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which is often a bit easier to maintain .. a matter of taste actually

```
void Start() 
{
    camera = Camera.main;
    // assuming that your camera points exactly forward (2D game like)
    var distance = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z - camera.tramsform.position.z);
    var frustumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    var frustrumWidth = frustumHeight * camera.aspect;

    // not anymore in pixel space but frustrum width in world coordinates
    // at the z distance of the spawner
    width = frustrumWidth / 2f;


    StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());
}

IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
{
    // looks dangerous but is fine for Coroutines as long as you yield somewhere
    while(true)
    {
        var new_obstacle = Instantiate(obstacle);
        new_obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.right * Random.Range(-width, width);

        if(camera.WorldToScreenPoint(new_obstacle.transform.position).y < Screen.height - 7)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(new_obstacle, true);
        }
       
        // In Coroutines a yield tells Unity to "pause" here, 
        // render this frame and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(maxTime);

        maxTime = 0.9f * maxTime;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    score += pontos * Time.deltaTime; 
}
```